# CSS values not applying to elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a css file that is meant to theme a page to be white on black, rather than black on white.

```
body {
background-color: black;
}
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 p {
    color: white;
}
```

but for some reason the `color: white;` is not applying to text elements on my page, an example is at https://jsfiddle.net/3abz7831/

**Things I have tried:**
The client has access to all required files.
Adding the color to the individual element style works just fine, but I'd rather not.
Changing where in the `<head>` the sheet is or moving it to the body does nothing.

Comment: jumbotron is messing with your style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate elements with comma:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    color: white;
}
```

and have to add this if you want your jumbotron to be white either

```
.jumbotron {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate styled elements by commas:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    color: white;
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbhqjLv3/)

Answer (score 0):

The rule `.jumbotron h1` is overriding your css rule. So create a rule which overrides it or add !important to the rule.

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

or  (worst solution)

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    color: white !important;
}
```